# Sed replace string with variable?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Im trying to replace string with variable with this command but not works

```
sed '/AXG/s/;/${HOMEx}/g'
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Might help to TAG the question; Linux? Mac?

Comment: I put linux in tag

Comment: my variable is HOMEx

Comment: Oh my bad. didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes. They prevent variable expansion.

```
sed "/AXG/s/;/${HOMEx}/g"
```

If HOMEx="test" this becomes:
    sed "/AXG/s/;/test/g"

Compare https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.htm and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html

Beware though: if the variable HOMEx contains something sed recognises you'll get an error. In this case the main things would be a backreference like "\1" or forward slash "/".

Comment: this give a error unknow character

Comment: Be careful about what's in the variable though. If it contains something sed recognises you'll have problems

Comment: yes I have problems with this my variable is SO big